# MySQL Query to prevent nested tree

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have Pages, when creating or editing a page, it's possible to assign a parent to that Page.

Now I need to write a query that returns the possible parents (so a query on the pages). The issue is I can only allow one level of depth, this means the user can't select a parent if that parent

- already has children
- also has a parent
- **can cause a nested relation!**

The last one is the crucial and difficult one, let me try to explain:

```
+----+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
| id | parent_id |     title     |                        |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
|  1 | NULL      | Mother        |                        |
|  2 | NULL      | Daughter      | <----- selected record |
|  3 | 2         | Granddaughter |                        |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
```

> I can't allow the 'Mother' to be in the collection of possible parents for the 'Daughter', since the 'Daughter' already has a Child, this would make the 'Granddaughter' a nested relation (remember, I can only allow one level).

### What I've done so far

I'm already only allowing records that **have no children**, **have no parents**

**But this stil returns the 'Mother' record when I'm editing the 'Daughter'**, since the 'Mother' doesn't have children or a parent, and is therefor allowed here, but it shouldn't be, because once I assign the 'Mother' as a child for the 'Daughter', I end up with a nested relation!

#### Basically

I need to ***"return an empty result if another row has the selected record's id as parent"***

Comment: The solution is simple, from what you describe, you cannot choose a parent at all for `Daughter` **because it has a children** (every parent choice would create a nested relation for this reason).. You just need to return an empty result if another row has your `id` as parent

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it, but I'm not sure how to return empty from mysql? During a query?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misunderstood the question. You want one level of depth, so:

You need to know the rows where the id is not equal to the id_parent of other rows (pages without children) and where id_parent is null (pages without parent).

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_parent FROM pages WHERE id_parent IS NOT NULL) AND id_parent IS NULL
```

The subquery returns all the ID pages with a valid id_parent. Then you select all rows without parent excepts the last selected. So you get all possible parents/children.

If you have the id of the page and you want to know if it has children or a parent (so if it valid), you can do it with 2 queries:

1) Check if it has a parent:

```
SELECT id_parent FROM pages WHERE id = YOUR_PAGE_ID
```

2) If the result is 'null', the page has not a parent, so let's check if it has children:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages WHERE id_parent = YOUR_PAGE_ID
```

If the result is 0, the page has not children, so it is a valid page.

With a single query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages WHERE id_parent = YOUR_PAGE_ID OR (id = YOUR_PAGE_ID AND id_parent IS NOT NULL)
```

You check if it has children or if it has a parent.

Comment: These are two possible solutions. The first contains a subquery (but it is actually a single query) and gives you **all possible parents**. The second tells you how many children **a specific page** has; if they're 0, the page is a possible parent. With the first you can show to user what parents he can select; with the second you can validate if a specific page can be used as a parent.

Comment: When I test your first query, I can still select the 'Mother', when I'm in the 'Child' page.. Do I need to combine the 1st and 2nd solution to make this work?

Comment: Do you think this can exist in one query? Or is that impossible?

Comment: Yes. With the first solution, just do the first query. If in the result there are the 2 pages that you want to relation, you can allow it, if not, avoid it. If you want to adopt the second solution but with a single query... I've just edited the answer.